# How to save ordered variables to a file

Tags: python

I need to save some variables to a file. I can can write to the file but I don't know how to order the contents of the file in python.

The file will contain a string paired with an integer and I want to order it from the highest integer to lowest.

> Data in the file:
>
> ```
> 3 third string
> 1 first string
> 2 second string
> ```
>
> Expected Output:
>
> ```
> 1 first string
> 2 second string
> 3 third string
> ```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice of people to downvote without reasoning... but it would help to know some more information. How are you saving the variables to a file (as in what format)? The `sorted` function can be used to order a list in Python, this may be of use

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have your input in a list as below. Then you can use sorted() function and then use the sorted list for writing  the file

```
    l=['3 third string','1 third string','2 third string']
    l=sorted(l,key=lambda x : int(x[0]))
    with open("A:\mygit\projects\Python\output_dir\sample.txt",'w+') as f:
        for line in l:
            f.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

Now say if you have a file containing the dis-ordered set of lines.Now if you want to read and order the same file, say sample.txt looks like as below:

```
    3 third string
    1 third string
    2 third string
```

Now the below code will, first read the file, convert it into a list ,sort it and write back it into the file:

```
    with open("sample.txt",'r') as f:
        l=[x.strip() for x in list(f)]

    l=sorted(l,key=lambda x : int(x[0]))

    with open("sample.txt",'w') as f:
        for line in l:
            f.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have to use standard python, take a look at the [json library.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Besides this, you can use the builtin `sorted()` function python has.

Comment: `json` is part of the standard library. Also, this doesn't actually explain how to apply either method.